# Dynamically setting href attribute using jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of url information which are rendered as table using jinja. I am trying to make the url a hyper link so that if i click on the link it will go it that url page.

**Sample url List**

```
myData = [["https://www.w3schools.com/",'tutorial site']]
```

**Jinja Code**

```
<tbody>
            {% for value in myData %} 
            <tr>
                <a href="{{ value[0].href }}"><td>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    {{ value[0] }}
                </td></a>
                <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %} 
</tbody>
```

I tried in this way but didnt work. How is it possible to set the value of href value dynamically with jinja code. In the above, if i click on `https://www.w3schools.com/` url in the table, that page should open in new tab of the browser

Comment: Just use `<a href="{{ value }}">`.

Comment: `myData` is a list of strings. What exactly do you expect `value[0]`, `value[0].href` and `value[1]` to be, when `value` is a string?

Comment: @DeepSpace There was a small mistake which i corrected now

Comment: So just use `value[0]` without `.href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `<a href="{{ value }}">`. I mean, if you put URLs in `myData` . Otherwise make MyData contain a list of dictionaries, `myData=[{"href": "https://www.w3schools.com/", "title": "tutorial site"} , ]` and then you can use `<a href="{{ value['href'] }}">`.

Comment: There was a mistake in the sample data given. Corrected now. I tried this way. But didnt work

Comment: with this new version of hte data you should use `value[0]` inside the curly braces.